# XAF - Stop auto save when trying to add new child in parent child view

Tags: c#, xaf

When trying to add record in child view, it require to save the parent record.
how can i stop this behavior?

[Look into the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCF4i.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you have a view that have collections let's say we have customer view that have listview of invoices, my problem is when creating new customer and before saving i try to add 1 invoice in its listview by clicking new button above the invoice listview, XAF ask me to save customer 1st before adding invoice, i want to add invoice without saving customer and save all at once, am i clear to you?

Comment: What version of XAF are you using? and what platform?

Comment: Version: 21.2.4, Web Platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to make it work unless you set LinkNewObjectToParentImmediately to false under Program.cs . But in this case there won't be any relationship between objects. You can override action by adding new controller but it is also useless in your case because there must an existing customer to link new invoice to.

Comment: In EF it is possible to add to the child collection without the parent having been saved. But to my knowledge XAF doesn't seem to take advantage of that.

Comment: @Kirsten you can do the same in XAF by setting LinkNewObjectToParentImmediately to false but as I said before it won't link two objects to each other. There is one way to achieve this. First set LinkNewObjectToParentImmediately to false then create new controller to override parent object's onSaving(). If there is not any linked current nested listview object find it and link it to parent object under controller.

Comment: Thank you. What kind of controller and what method were you putting the override in? How do you get the child add button to show?

Comment: My work around is by adding pop up action to open new record within it, but my problem is when you close the popup you can't edit the new record (by Edit action), you can edit by inline edit only or by custom action